# Laravel query join not return as I want

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Firstly sorry for my bad English.

I would like to show category with count listings in this category like:

Category name (5)

Ok, I have 2 tables: categories | listings.

```
$categories = Categories::join('listings', 'categories.id', '=', 'listings.category_id')
    ->select('categories.*', DB::raw('count(listings.id) as listings'))
    ->groupBy('categories.id')
    ->get();
```

This works ok, and shows ok but only if there are any results with category id in listings table. Is it possible to show category name with 0 if any results without 2 sql queries? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use a `leftJoin` instead of  `join`.

Comment: what example of result does this show, and what example of result do you expect?

Comment: @aynber Thank you very much !